# Date function in standard SQL in Google bigquery

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery

What are the date functions like (YEAR(), MONTH(), DATEADD(), DATEDIFF(),...) in standard SQL of Goolge bigquery?

I used functions [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference) when --use_legacy_sql is true, but they don't work with standard SQL.

Comment: See also the guide on [Migrating from legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/migrating-from-legacy-sql#function_comparison). It has a table comparing functions between the two dialects.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an equivalent to WEEK() in standard sql. Is that correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find all Date functions for BigQuery Standard SQL here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#date-functions

Specifically [EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#extract) returns the value corresponding to the specified date part. The part must be one of:

```
DAYOFWEEK (Returns 1-7, where 1=Sunday ... 7=Saturday)
DAY
DAYOFYEAR
MONTH
QUARTER (Returns 1-4)
YEAR
```

See also `DATE_ADD`, `DATE_SUB`, `DATE_DIFF` and rest for respectively DATEADD(), DATEDIFF() ...

Comment: Note that DATEADD, DATEDIFF etc functions in legacy SQL actually worked with TIMESTAMP type, not DATE, so their counterparts in standard SQL are TIMESTAMP_ADD, TIMESTAMP_DIFF etc.